# phpMyAdmin - Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Setup a new instance of phpMyadmin and I am able to sign with root and password, but when I do the following I am unable to login. Also able to sign into mysql via command line.

```
 create user 'user'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
 grant all on user.* to 'user'@'localhost';
```

The phyMyAdmin config shows the following:

```
  <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 192.168.1.1/24
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from 192.168.1.1/24
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Deny from All
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? What apache version do you have? What phpmyadmin version do you have?

Comment: phpmyadmin version: 4.4.15.10
apache version: 2.4.6

Comment: and the exact error message/ web response when you log in? Maybe even the apache error/access log for that interaction.

Comment: I don't see any interaction in any of the logs. But I will dig through them again shortly and post back soon.

Comment: What you showed is a portion of the Apache configuration not the configuration for PHPMyAdmin which is stored in `config.inc.php` in the PHPMyAdmin folder. Have you updated the PHPMyAdmin configuration file with the credentials you created?

Comment: Let me get back to the config, and I will update the posting in the next few days.